# Use findviewbyid in different activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

How do I use `findViewById` in a different `Activity`?

Right now I have a `View` that I made called `DrawingView` which contains a `Canvas` to draw on.  In another `SettingsActivity` I have a `Button` to allow they to choose a `Color`.

I need to be able to access the `DrawingView` that is in my `activity_main.xml` from my separate settings activity.

When I call `findViewById()` it returns `null` because it is searching for an id thats in a different activity.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: View object can be accessed within visible activity context only. If View is not available and if you try to use findViewByID, It will crash with NullPointerException.

Comment: Have you used setContentView in Settings Activity for activity_main.xml?

Comment: This is somewhat related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236725/how-to-change-a-view-from-a-different-activity) where I suggested you look into [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to pass the data back from the settings activity

Comment: @MustansarSaeed wont that change the view away from settings so they can no long select the color to change?

Comment: I would alternatively suggest a popup dialog with a radiogroup if you are just setting colors

Comment: In order to use `findViewById`, the particular xml should be set as the content in that activity

Comment: @MustansarSaeed why would the settings activity use activity_main.xml? MainActivity and the settings activity are different. Setting the content view of the settings activity to the main activity makes no sense even if findViewById would work

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you that did work for me.  I had some other issues last time that I had to figure out first.  I wish I could choose you as correct answer!

Comment: Yeah, it was a broad topic, the documentation has a very good explanation, and I don't have a test Android environment around at the moment to test anything. You're welcome, though

Answer (score 4):

Accessing the view from another activity is going to be a problem, and even if you can arrange to get to the main activity's layout hierarchy, it's not the right way to do things.

The best way to deal with this is to implement a [`PreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/PreferenceChangeListener.html) in the activity that has your `DrawingView`. It can then respond to the change in preference value and change the color in the `DrawingView`. See the docs for how to implement the listener.

This assumes that you are saving the color choice in a `SharedPreferences` object so it will be persistent. (This is something that happens automatically if you are using the built-in preferences framework, or you can write the choice yourself.) If you aren't using `SharedPreferences`, then the suggestion by @cricket_007 to use `startActivityForResult` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Isn't this assuming the use of a `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: @cricket_007 - Not necessarily. It only assumes that the color choice is saved in shared preferences. (Of course, that may not be a good assumption. I'll update the answer accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the link in the comments to this user's other question, you can see more of the code they are using

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks the startActivityforResult did work for me!